# Opens a new window that is automatically size by content

Tags: javascript, html

I open a new JavaScript window using the following code:

```
function meas() {
  ViewImg = window.open('http://localhost/meas.php', 'ViewImg', 'width=auto,height=auto', 'status=no');
}
```

I want to make the window open in width and length depending on the size of the display it has.

What I'm trying to do is that when the page loads, the size will automatically change based on what's on the page

If there is a big picture, the window will be large.

If there is a small picture, the window will be small

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Which type of content do you have here means it is an image or any other data?

Comment: I have a millions of ideas. But if you tell us more (and by more I mean, wayyyy more) about your content, we will be able to help you ^^

Comment: As far as I know, you must specify the width and height of the desired window, otherwise you must resize the window from the linked file itself. Take a look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_resizeto.asp

Comment: I have just picture

Comment: What about some kind of lightbox, instead of a new window? Keep in mind browsers often block opening new windows.

Comment: I updated my message that it really was not understood

Comment: mikiqex, This is an excellent idea and this is the next step. Right now it's important for me to solve this problem because that's what my boss wants